# How to Install Boost Asio?

Tags: c++, perl, build, openssl, boost-asio

I have just found out that Boost Asio depends on openssl. I am trying to build openssl so I can add it as dep to boost but I am having a hard time doing so. Could please someone point me to how can I build the openssl library?

Github openssl: https://github.com/openssl/openssl#build-and-install

I have just insalled perl and when running perl Configure I get:
Compilation failed in require at c:/Users/AppData/xxxxx/site/lib/IPC/Cmd.pm line 235.

Could please someone point out how to use Boost Asio "easily"?

Comment: I’d recommend using a package manager such as Conan or Vcpkg.

Comment: Thanks very much. I am on windows and I don't know what are these terms or how to use them. Could you please point me out somewhere detailed or expand plz?

Comment: *"when running perl Configure"* : I suppose you run this from the command prompt in Windows? What version of Windows? From the command prompt: What is the output of `perl --version`? and `where perl`?

Comment: Yes using cmd. Output of version is:
This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Comment: @Vero Ok, and what version of windows? How did you install  perl? Did you download the openssl source using `git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git` as described [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl#build-and-install) ?

Comment: I have just git clone the github repo. I am using windows 10 and downloaded perl from perl.org/get.html#win32. Could you please help, also the below does not work for me? I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 2):

> I have just insalled perl and when running perl Configure I get: Compilation failed in require at c:/Users/AppData/xxxxx/site/lib/IPC/Cmd.pm line 235.

The following worked for me on Windows 11, using Strawberry Perl version 5.32.1, and "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022":

- I downloaded the openssl source:

  ```
  >git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
  ```
- Then, I needed to install nasm.exe: I downloaded the installer for the latest release here:
  https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.16rc9/win64/nasm-2.16rc9-installer-x64.exe .After installation, I updated `PATH` such that `nasm.exe` could be found from the command prompt.
- Then from the openssl source directory:

  ```
  >perl Configure
  Configuring OpenSSL version 3.2.0-dev for target VC-WIN64A
  Using os-specific seed configuration
  Created configdata.pm
  Running configdata.pm
  Created makefile.in
  Created makefile
  Created include\openssl\configuration.h

  **********************************************************************
  ***                                                                ***
  ***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
  ***                                                                ***
  ***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
  ***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
  ***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
  ***                                                                ***
  ***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
  ***                                                                ***
  ***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
  ***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL.md file first)      ***
  ***                                                                ***
  **********************************************************************
  ```

Comment: Holy crap. +1 for the answer, but how on earth is the windows ecosystem still accepting such sharply user-hostile cruft? I *know* that competing, better ways exist - each with some drawbacks, but somehow this is still the canonical answer.

Comment: Thank you again but this does not work for me, I installed nasm and added it to the path and also can run the command on cmd: nasm -v, output: NASM version 2.15.05 compiled on Aug 28 2020. But still perl Configure (or + VC-WIN64A) gives same error: Compilation failed in require at c:/Users/.../lib/IPC/Cmd.pm line 235. Could someone please help?

Comment: @Vero Could you send me the complete log (output) of running `perl Configure` ?

Comment: I read this: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES-WINDOWS.md
1. I cloned the repo: https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
2. I downloaded perl and when I excute: ```perl -v``` I get output below,
```
This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)
Binary build 0000 [25391a6d] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Oct 28 2020 18:24:51
```

Comment: 3. I downloaded nasm and added it to the ```PATH``` and when I call in cmd ```nasm -v``` I get the below,
```NASM version 2.15.05 compiled on Aug 28 2020```

Comment: 4. I then go to the openssl folder I open cmd and I run: ```perl Configure``` and I get the below,
```
Failure!  build file wasn't produced.
Please read INSTALL.md and associated NOTES-* files.  You may also have to
look over your available compiler tool chain or change your configuration.```

Comment: ```
Can't locate Win32/Console.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Win32::Console module) (@INC contains: H:/..../openssl/util/perl c:/Users/../AppData/Local/activestate/cache/.../site/lib c:/Users/../AppData/Local/activestate/cache/.../lib H:/..../openssl/external/perl/Text-Template-1.56/lib) at c:/Users/farid/AppData/Local/activestate/cache/cda7f279/site/lib/ActivePerl/Config.pm line 400.```

Comment: Compilation failed in require at c:/Users/.../AppData/Local/activestate/cache/.../site/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Users/.../AppData/Local/activestate/cache/.../site/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Users/.../AppData/Local/activestate/cache/.../site/lib/IPC/Cmd.pm line 235.
```
I am using ```Windows 10 Pro```. OS Build: ```19044.2251```

Comment: that is all the steps I followed :)

Comment: @Vero Thanks. Seems like your perl installation is missing some modules. I am not using ActiveState perl, but [Strawberry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/). Anyway, can you try install Win32::Console module, and then rerun `perl Configure` ?

Comment: Thanks so much, I installed Strawberry and it works fine. Just still missing some header files e.g. <openssl/ssl.h> and <openssl/opensslv.h> only .in exists. How can generate these files please?

Comment: @Vero Ok, great! Can you show the error messages you get?

Comment: I am buiding locally in VS using premake, the error is the standard one: H:\Mine....\openssl\test\helpers\ssltestlib.h(13,11): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/ssl.h': No such file or directory. When I look into the folder there is only ssl.in, ssl2.h and ssl3.h. Also same for opensslv, only opensslv.in exists.

Comment: @Vero Do you get this error when you run the test suite?

Comment: Not I haven't run any tests. I saw on the website that I should run three other commands after perl Configure i.e. nmake=nmake test, nmake install but I did not as nmake is not recognized for me in cmd.

Comment: @Vero I am running the commands from a "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022". Here you will have nmake command..

Comment: Thanks very much. I went to Tools > Command Line > Developer Command Prompt and then I run both:
```
nmake
nmake test
```
but ```nmake install``` fails: 
```
Could Not Find H:\Mine\...\openssl\libcrypto-3-x64.*
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cmd' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.```

Comment: @Vero Yes, I just tried `nmake test` and it fails here too.. I am looking into it.

Comment: Agree looking again at the log ```nmake test``` fails with same error ```NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'```

Comment: @Vero Added issue for failed test here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/19759

Comment: I see thank you. There is nothing I can do now my side. I just wait I guess :) Please let me know if I can help somehow.

Comment: @Vero All tests pass now here after I downgraded NASM to version 2.15.05, see https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/19759 for more information